# Check if all input with required label is not empty

Tags: jquery, html

I have defined some necessary fields that are indicated by a required (*) label with an text input next to it. When I submit, I want to make sure that all of these required labels' text inputs are not empty after the button submit.

This is what I have for HTML (https://jsfiddle.net/mmsawjwr/5/):

```
<div class="col-md-12">

<label class="required" for="lblFirstName">First Name:</label>
<input id="txtFirstName" type="text"/>

<label class="required" for="lblLastName">Last Name:</label>
<input id="txtLastName" type="text"/>

</div>

<div class="col-md-12">

<label class="required" for="lblEmail">Email:</label>
<input id="txtEmail" type="text"/>

<label class="required" for="lblPhone">Phone number:</label>
<input id="txtPhone" type="text"/>

</div>

<button type="button" class="btnSaveAll" value="Save" style="margin-bottom:5px;">Save</button>
```

At first, I was going to hardcode and check each id individually, but I figured that there should be a dynamic way to check this. Any guidance/direction will be appreciated!

Comment: Where are `*` in your code?

Comment: take a look at this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation

Comment: add `required` attribute to the inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to move your required class to the inputs, or use the html5 attribute required on your inputs and then select all the inputs with required using this 
`$('input[required="true"]')`

I have provided a required class solution here: https://jsfiddle.net/mmsawjwr/32/
You may want to build on this solution by removing the class if the input is valid with an else statement as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully, this is supported by HTML itself: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation

You can indicate `required` inputs (eg. `<input ... required />` to use built in form validation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-required